# Excell VBA Shell command not working but it does work from the windows command window

Tags: excel, vba, windows, shell

The code below Works with Excel 2016
When the user clicks a cell in column A (after the first few header rows are checked)
The value of the contents of the cell is stored in the string variable stockcode.
The Sub Spark() is where the problem lies, in particular Call Shell(stAppName, 0)

```
  stAppName = "C:\Autoit\Spark_test_10_Excel.a3x " & stockcode
  Debug.Print stAppName
  Call Shell(stAppName, 0)
  The application being called displays a chart.
```

In the debug window you can see the call string C:\Autoit\Spark_test_10_Excel.a3x BHP
If I copy and paste that output into the windows 10 search window the string opens the app and displays a chart perfectly. I also compiled the Autoit script to an EXE That performed exactly as described above. No difference.
Also not the Notepad test commented out. That also worked perfectly.

I guess this is problem is security related. I have tried numerous workarounds none worked so far.

Any suggestions will be gratefully received

```
Option Explicit
 
Public stAppName As String
Public stockcode As String
 
Private Type POINTAPI
    x As Long
    y As Long
End Type
 
Private Type MSG
    hwnd As Long
    Message As Long
    wParam As Long
    lParam As Long
    time As Long
    pt As POINTAPI
End Type
 
Private Declare Function PeekMessage Lib "user32" _
Alias "PeekMessageA" _
(ByRef lpMsg As MSG, ByVal hwnd As Long, _
ByVal wMsgFilterMin As Long, _
ByVal wMsgFilterMax As Long, _
ByVal wRemoveMsg As Long) As Long
 
Private Const PM_NOREMOVE = &H0
 
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Message As MSG
    'check for left-mouse button clicks.
    PeekMessage Message, 0, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE

    If Message.Message = 512 Then
        Debug.Print "You clicked cell: " & Selection.Address, Selection.Value
    End If
    
    On Error GoTo FoundAnError 'the user probably clicked somewhare not in column A in the sheet
        stockcode = Selection.Value
        Call Spark
    
FoundAnError:
    MsgBox ("there was a VBA code error it should have been addressed")
End Sub

Sub Spark()
Debug.Print "Spark: " & Selection.Address, Selection.Value
    If ActiveCell.Column = 1 Then
        If stockcode = "Ticker Symbol" Then
            Debug.Print "Ticker", stockcode
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        If Selection.Value = "" Then
            Debug.Print "No stock code ", stockcode
            Exit Sub
        End If
            Debug.Print "stock code in call ", stockcode
            'Shell "Notepad", vbNormalFocus 'Yes this works as a test
            'On Error GoTo 0
            stAppName = "C:\Autoit\Spark_test_10_Excel.a3x " & stockcode
            Debug.Print stAppName
'EDIT             
           'Call Shell(stAppName, 0)This does not work!
           Shell "cmd.exe /C " & stAppName, vbHide 'Works
'This Works Thanks FaneDuru 

        End If
End Sub
```

This is the output from the debug window running the above code
You clicked cell: $A$7      BHP
Spark: $A$7   BHP
stock code in call          BHP
C:\Autoit\Spark_test_10_Excel.a3x BHP

Comment: Please, try `stAppName = """C:\Autoit\Spark_test_10_Excel.a3x"" """ & stockcode & """"`...

Comment: If it still does not work, try calling the `Shell` in the next way: `Shell "cmd.exe /C " & stAppName, vbHide`.

Comment: Didn't any of the above suggestions solve your problem? A little feedback did not kill anybody...

Comment: Thank You FaneDuru 
It is interesting that this Application has been working for years! Only recently with the switch to Windows 10 and Excel 2016 did the code fail. There is a lot of discussion on the net about Excel VBA Macros being Being used by malicious software developers. This App I created is used by a small group on different computers. I guess I can look forward to more issues with security settings on their PC's. The switch to Windows11 with the encrypted ID chip and added layers of security is going to be a big hassle for honest citizens. I will report any issues I find here.....

Comment: I am afraid that I am not able to understand the answer to my main question: Did one of the above suggested solution solve your problem? The rest should come only after clarifying of this aspect, I think...

Comment: Hi FaneDuru
I gave the answer in the code note the edit:

'EDIT             
           'Call Shell(stAppName, 0)This does not work!
           Shell "cmd.exe /C " & stAppName, vbHide 'Works

I did not want to close by answering the thread just yet until I have done testing on other PC's.

Comment: If you do not say anything about an eventual 'edit', we cannot check all the time what has been changed in the question code... Now I understand what you say, but I would like to emphasize that it works in that way **only for paths not having any space in their string**. You missed an important part of my comment, I'm afraid... You should build the command line as: `stAppName = """C:\Autoit\Spark_test_10_Excel.a3x"" """ & stockcode & """"`. This version will work on any path (any computer), even if there spaces exist in them. Otherwise, it may fail in the above mentioned circumstances.

Comment: I did first try stAppName = """C:\Autoit\Spark_test_10_Excel.a3x"" """ & stockcode & """" and It did not work, When I checked the debug window there appeared to extra quotes in the string. I was in a hurry, This project is driving me nuts! So I quickly tried the next option that was a success. It's 1AM in the morning here so its a bit late to test now but will try again and see if I can make it work. Thanks for the warning about spaces.  Will report back.